# Manipulating the Style menu in WYGWAM?

Tags: wygwam, config

This thing drives me nuts. There is no reason this thing should be so small. I'd love to:

1. Make it larger, both vertically and horizontally; and
2. Style the text inside. I don't necessarily want it to adopt the style of the element it creates, either.

Are these options I have any control over?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to Add-ons -> Fieldtypes and select Wygwam.

Edit the relevant Editor configuration.

Enter a CSS file you want to use in the "CSS File" field I use a template so enter: `/css-javascript/css-wygwam` (template group/template name format), but you can use any frontend URL.  This controls the styling inside the Wygwam Text field.

Next add an advanced setting called `stylesSet` and enter the style reference and url to your JS file:

```
mystyles:/themes/site_themes/mysite/js/js-wygwam.js
```

You used to be able to reference a template in this URL, but I think that stopped working with a newer version (could be wrong!). Note the style reference "mystyles".

Here's an example JS file:

```
CKEDITOR.addStylesSet('mystyles',[
    {name:'Content text', element:'p'},
    {name:'Leadin text', element:'p', attributes: { 'class': 'leadin' }},
    {name:'Head2', element:'h2'},
    {name:'Head2+border', element:'h2', attributes: { 'class': 'line' }},
    {name:'Head3', element:'h3'},
    {name:'Read More', element:'a', attributes: { 'class': 'showtext' }},
    {name:'More Text', element:'div', attributes: { 'class': 'moretext' }}
]);
```

Note the same style reference "mystyles".  This builds the dropdown menu in Wygwam.

Your styles will be reflected in the menu as well as the text area.

[image: Grab of wygwam customised style dropdown]

Your CSS file is loaded in the head of the CKEditor iframe, so you can manipulate the dropdown separately:

```
.cke_panel_list li a
```

But it's difficult to target each individual style as they're referenced as #cke_xxx, although once you've built the dropdown and the styles you want, you can specify these unique references in the CSS file.